# Custom background of button not showing up in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I've made a custom .xml file with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape>
          <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
          <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape>
          <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
          <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

And in my activity_main.xml I have the following button:

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/buttonname"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

If I hover over `@drawable/buttonname` I see my intended design, but instead of the design, my button background is my `colorPrimary` from my styles folder, both in preview at Visual Studio as well as when it is emulated. I have already restarted Visual Studio several times, without avail. Am I forgetting something? Is there some solution to this problem?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the `xml ` file you posted, we find you set all the two states into color `colorAccent` which is also consistent with the result. But I also find that you set the `android:textColor` to `colorAccent` which make the text invisible because its font color is the same as the background color. What kind of effect do you want?

Comment: I want to have a button that is transparant apart from the border and the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background works if I change the Button to a TextView and has the desired layout after I put the `android:gravity="center"` tag in.